# Elasticsearch: filter documents on missing field unless other field exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing an Elasticsearch query, that filters out all document, where a specific field is missing via

```
query: {
  filtered: {
    filter: {
      bool: {
        should: {
          bool: {
            must: {
              term: 'someCondition'
            },
            must_not: {
              missing: {field: 'somefield'}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected. Now I need to make this `missing`filter conditional, so that it will only match, if another field does not exist.

I have tried converting my `must_not` to a `should` like this:

```
should: {
  missing: {field: 'somefield'},
  exists: {'field': 'somotherfield'}
}
```

But that does not seem to work.

To clarify: "SELECT * from docs WHERE (somefield IS NOT NULL OR someotherfield IS NOT NULL)"

Comment: And if you write it out, you suddenly see how it's supposed to be...

`should: [[{exists:{field:somefield}}, {exists:{field:'someotherfield'}}]]`

Answer (score -1):

Try query like this:

```json
"filters" : [ {
"missing" : {
        "field" : "somefield"
  }
}, {
  "not" : {
    "filter" : {
      "missing" : {
        "field" : "somotherfield"
      }
    }
  }
} ]
```